# WebBrower.Navigate() doesn't load targeted URL

Tags: c#, .net, url, browser

When invoking the `Navigate()` WebBrowser plugin for .NET C# it doesn't load the targeted URL if the window is not maximized. I'm telling the program to load a file on disk. It all works well if the window is maximized but if the window starts up unmaximized (i.e., a region) the web browser doesn't load.
I'm telling the browser to load the page on the windows form load event and it is located on a panel. And it only loads correctly if the window starts maximized otherwise the `WebBrowser.Navigate` won't move a needle, even if the url is incorrect!

Is this a bug?

Comment: Here it is: **private void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) { webBrowser.Navigate(new Uri("file://" + Environment.CurrentDirectory + "/html/page.html"));}**

Comment: Hi, more details: if I use "Application.Run(new LoginForm()); if (LoginHandler.LoggedIn) { Application.Run(Conf.MainForm); }" it works only maximized but if I create the main form inside the Program.cs it starts working with no need to be maximized, i.e.: "Application.Run(new MainForm());", why this behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

I was having a similar issue - only the first Url would be loaded. Although I never set `AllowNavigation` to `false`, manually setting it to `true` before attempting `Navigate()` solved it for me:

```
webBrowser.AllowNavigation = true;
webBrowser.Navigate(...);
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, your problem is that it doesn't navigate when the window is minimized. That's actually normal behavior.
If you want it to load while minimized, I suggest using a thread or a pool. Your UI won't be updated when it's minimized... Maybe it will *load* it, but you wouldn't see any differences because the UI is definitely "frozen" when it's minimized.